# How to copy all images from a src folder to a dist folder recursively using copy files npm module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, file-copying

Using the copy files command, how can I copy images (.png, .jpg) from a "src" folder to the "dist" folder, while preserving the same filepaths internally. Should also work recursively.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/copyfiles

I have this

```
copyfiles(["src/**/*.png", "dist"], {u:2}, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error occurred while copying", err);
    }
    console.log("folder(s) copied to destination");
});
```

But it doesn't seem to work. It creates the `src` folder inside `dist` folder.

Thanks

Comment: The docs say to use the long version of the option names. So use `up` instead of `u`.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out

```
copyfiles(["src/**/*.png", "dist"], 1, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error occurred while copying", err);
    }
    console.log("folder(s) copied to destination");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Accroding to the documentation in the [README of copyfiles](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/copyfiles#programic-api), if you want to provide options to `copyfiles` as an object, you should provide full names of options:

```js
const copyOptions = { up: true, error: true };
copyfiles(["src/**/*.png", "dist"], copyOptions, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.log("Error occurred while copying", err);
    }
    console.log("folder(s) copied to destination");
});
```